# understanding equality from istream_iterator

Tags: c++, stl, istream-iterator

Can someone please explain why this istream_iterator code.

```
// code extract from SGI STL istream_iterator class
bool _M_equal(const istream_iterator& __x) const {
   return (_M_ok == __x.M_ok) && (!_M_ok || _M_stream == __x._M_stream);
}
```

works and is not just written as

```
bool _M_equal(const istream_iterator& __x) const {
   return (_M_ok == __x.M_ok) && (_M_stream == __x._M_stream);
}
```

I don't understanding the reason for including !_M_ok. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`_M_stream == __x._M_stream` has undefined behaviour if either `_M_ok` or `__x._M_ok` is false.